# How to test local variables inside java protected method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4, powermock

I am trying to find a way to test a local variable declared and initiated inside a protected method.  This is my code. I would like to test the "**id**" with "**someText**" is being added to the **context** and removed in finally block.  is there any way to test it in java? Any help is appreciated.

```
public abstract class BaseTransaction {

    protected Status handleTransaction() {

        Map<String, String> context = new HashMap();
        context.put("id","someText");

        try {
            //some other method calls
        } finally {
            context.remove("id");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why?  `context` is a local variable, so it's going out of scope when the method ends, anyway.  What difference does it make whether `"id"` is removed?

Comment: You could move the context variable outside the protected method to test it, but as @azurefrog has stated above, when the method ends, the mapping will have already been deleted so the Map will be empty.

Comment: Best way is to put the protected methods under same package name under test. This will ensure that they are accessible, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186648/testing-protected-method-with-junit

Comment: Almost certainly you have too much in the one method. Splitting up may not necessarily involve adding objects/fields. As always, composition is preferable to inheritance.

Comment: @tostao *Local variables* are not accessible, no matter what package the class is in.

Comment: @azurefrog context is being used for logging mechanism. If something goes wrong with in the try block, our contextManager look for the context and logs the id in error message. That's the reason I wanted to remove it after making certain method calls in try block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't test `context`, that's too low level, but if you insist, change the code to:

```
protected Status handleTransaction() {
    Map<String, String> context = new HashMap<>();
    context.put("id", "someText");
    try {
        return handleContext(context);
    } finally{
        context.remove("id");
    }
}
protected Status handleContext(Map<String, String> context) {
    //some other method calls
}
```

You can now mock `handleContext` and call `handleTransaction`, to test that `context` map has correct content when `handleContext` is called.

You can also call `handleContext` directly, to test that it reacts correctly with various content in the `context` map.

Basically, you've split the logic of the original method into **2 units** that can be *independently* tested.